# How can I add 1 day to this JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function AgregarDias(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    var dateFormated = result.toISOString().substr(0,10);
    //dateFormated.setDate(dateFormated.getDate() + days);
    return dateFormated;
}
```

Any ideas, i've tried with too much ways

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days to JavaScript Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at [Moment](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function AgregarDias(date, days) {
    var dateFormated = new Date(date);
    dateFormated.setDate(dateFormated.getDate() + days);
    return dateFormated.toISOString().substr(0,10);
}
```

I am not sure why you are doing:

```
var dateFormated = result.toISOString().substr(0,10);
```

You should be able to work directly with the new Date object.

Comment: Ok, if you want to format the Date, you will first need to transform the date like above, then format it after the new date has been calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
result.setDate(result.getDate() + days)
```

Hope that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function AgregarDias(date,days) {
   var dateAdded = new Date(date);
   dateAdded.setDate(dateAdded.getDate() + days);
   return dateAdded;
}   
var datecustom = AgregarDias('2016-09-02',5);
alert(datecustom);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function AgregarDias(date, days) {
    var newDate = new Date(date.setTime( date.getTime() + days * 86400000 ));
    console.log(newDate);
    return newDate;
}

AgregarDias(new Date(), 1);
```